# Filter file completion list

Tags: ins-completion

When I write markdown and want to insert an image, i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F comes in handy. I know that I can filter by typing a few characters that precede the filename, but actually what I want is either type `*.jpg` and see the completion list filter on jpegs or have an option to filter the completion list once it is open on `*.jpg`

How can I improve my local file selection workflow, preferably without a plugin?

Comment: Why restrict your options with "preferably without a plugin". Pretty sure there are plugins that expand `ctrl-x` completion to use wildcards in the way you describe.

Comment: That's why I wrote preferably. I get a long way without plugins and use them where appropriate. When there is a Vim native solution I prefere it over many tiny plugins cumbersome to keep current (using no plug-in manager, only Vim8 packages)

Comment: Fair enough but if it's "prefer native but will use plugin if need be" you don't really have to mention that as that's pretty much everyone's stance...never seen anyone say "preferably _with_ a plugin". ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant example with explanations can be found under `:h complete()`

```
function! MyCompleteFileName()
    " match a (potential) wildcard preceding cursor position
    " note: \f is a filename character, see :h 'isfname'
    let l:pattern = matchstr(strpart(getline('.'), 0, col('.') - 1), '\v(\f|\*|\?)*$')
    " set the matches
    call complete(col('.') - len(l:pattern), getcompletion(l:pattern, "file"))
    " must return an empty string to show the menu
    return ''
endfunction

" rebind <C-X><C-F> to invoke our custom function
inoremap <C-X><C-F> <C-R>=MyCompleteFileName()<CR>
```

Comment: That fails with a lot of error messages: (can't copy from `:messages`): E15: invalid expression: \v(\f|\|\?)*$

Comment: @JohnDoe Somehow, I've lost an opening quote while copying the code. That's all.