# Disable expansion of environment variables when completing filenames

Tags: environment-variables

Let's suppose I have the following environment variable

```
1| export  my__files=$HOME/Documents/MyFiles
```

Now let's suppose I am editing the file `main.txt` (see content below)

```
1| foo
2| bar
3| $my__files/█
```

If I press `<C-x><C-f>` (complete filename) while in insert mode in the current cursor position, it will expand the environment variable and start listing the files and directories present within that specific directory

```
1| foo
2| bar
3| /home/mario/Documents/MyFiles/DCBooks/█
   /home/mario/Documents/MyFiles/DCBooks/
   /home/mario/Documents/MyFiles/DCExperiments/
   /home/mario/Documents/MyFiles/DCPrograms/
   /home/mario/Documents/MyFiles/DCRemoteRepos/
   /home/mario/Documents/MyFiles/Music/
```

My question is: When using file completion in front an environment variable is it possible to make `vim` not to expand it and just start listing files within the directory that is represented by the environment variable?

Comment: I’m not sure this happens for me in regular vim. Can you try with `vim -u NONE`? I’m pretty sure the usual mapping is `<C-x><C-f>`

Comment: I'm not stating that the usual mapping `<C-x><C-f>` doesn't work, I'm just stating that the environment variable expands to its literal value when pressing that combination of keys, but I don't want this behavior to occur. I don't want the environment variable to be expanded, that's why I was wondering if there is an option that disable that behavior. Note that `<C-x><C-f>` lists all unhidden files within a directory, which I want to use, but I repeat, I don't want the environment variable to be replaced with its literal value.

Comment: and I’m saying I’m not sure I’ve ever seen that happen, and that it could perhaps be from a plugin. The fact that the keys in the question are different from the usual strengthen my guess, but it’s a shot in the dark. That’s why I asked if this happened for you without a vimrc or with a minimal vimrc.

Comment: Any "file finding" function needs to expand an envvar, so you can't do with standard options. You can write your own custom completion function like this: build list of expanded names, and then shrink it back before feeding to `complete()`. See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21218/filter-file-completion-list/21221#21221) for example of custom complete.

Comment: I believe that is how file expansion works. Vim will always exapnd environment variables. There is a todo item about it.

Comment: For those of you who might care as to how to get the `to-do` list from vim: You just need to execute `:help todo` within `vim`.