# Ignore a filetype when opening but not when using insert-mode popup-menu

Tags: ins-completion

Using `:h wildignore`, I can ignore certain types of files or certain folders when searching through them to open one of them. But that also means those files and directories will be ignored when I try to insert their filepath with `:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F`.

Is there a way I can ignore, say, all `jpg` files when trying to open them using `:edit` but not ignore them when trying to insert their filepath using `:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F` in a file?

Comment: Seconded; I've just noticed this problem when writing LaTeX documents—I can't use `<C-x><C-f>` to insert image names for including figures!

Comment: How about this Q&A: [Filter file completion list](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21218/filter-file-completion-list)? Does it answer your question too?

Comment: @Matt, yeah, thanks, man. It works perfectly. In fact, it works **more** perfectly. I can now use `**/*.jpg` to populate the suggestion list! Freaking awesome man!! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I have is to disable `'wildignore'` while in Insert mode. I haven't found any untoward side-effects, but it would have been nice to have a pre-complete/post-complete pair of events (`CompleteDone` is almost pre-complete, but `CompleteChanged` is not pre).

```
augroup NoWildignoreInsert
  au!
  au InsertEnter *
        \ if !exists('b:old_wildignore') |
        \   let b:old_wildignore=&wildignore |
        \   set wildignore& |
        \ endif
  au InsertLeave *
        \ if exists('b:old_wildignore') |
        \   let &wildignore=b:old_wildignore |
        \   unlet b:old_wildignore |
        \ endif
augroup END
```